# How to rate limit a NestJS API by multiple time intervals?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I am trying to rate limit my API with @NestJs/throttler.
I want to set **two** different limit caps:

- 100 requests per 1 second
- 10,000 requests per 24 hours.

Setting either one of these rate limits is [explained in the docs](https://github.com/nestjs/throttler) and is pretty straight forwad. But, setting both limitations is not articulated in the docs.

How can I rate limit my API by **both** time intervals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I told you on Discord, with `@nestjs/throttler`, this functionality currently doesn't exist. You can have one or the other, or you can override the global config to be more specific for one endpoint, but there's not currently a way to have two limits set up.